# Delaying a Bedika

Tags: halacha, niddah

If a woman who has a Veset Shelo Kavua and has a makka (cut), can she delay the bedika of the Onah Beinonis a couple of days after when the cut will heal otherwise she will make herself a Nidda with the Bedika. Granted she will be forbidden to her husband until after she does the bedika but is she allowed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This would seemingly be a machlokes between the Bach and other Achronim

The Shulchan Aruch YD 184:9 says:

> שאר נשים צריכות בדיקה כשיגיע הוסת עבר הוסת ולא בדקה ולא הרגישה טהורה בלא בדיקה וי"א שאסורה עד שתבדוק אם יש לה וסת קבוע או שהוא יום ל' אע"פ שאינו קבוע (והכי נהוג וכן הוא לקמן סימן קפ"ט)

> 9. The rest of the women must inspect themselves when their veset comes. If the time of the veset passes, and she has not checked, and she has not felt a sensation - she is pure without checking. There are those that say that she is forbidden until she inspects, if she has a set veset or if it is the 30th day even if it is not her set veset. RAMA: This is how the custom is practiced. Similarly, see Siman 189.

The Shach 184:23 brings a machlokes about a case when the woman missed the bedika with the Bach bring machmir:

> עד שתבדוק. כתב בית יוסף ממשמעות הפוסקים דאפילו איחרה זמן מה אחר הוסת כיון שבדקה ומצאה טהורה טהורה והב"ח פסק דיש להחמיר כמסקנת המרדכי בשם רא"מ וכסה"ת וכהגהת ש"ד בשם סמ"ק דדוקא בבדקה עצמה מיד לאחר וסתה תוך שיעור וסתה אבל לא בדקה תוך הזמן אף על פי שלאח"כ בדקה עצמה ומצאה טהורה טמאה דחזקה אורח בזמנו בא ונפל לארץ ע"כ ולקמן סי' ק"צ סנ"א נתבאר איזה שיעור וסתה ע"ש

The Pischei Teshuva in 184:19 says that we are not careful about this Bach

> שתבדוק. עבה"ט בשם ב"ח והאחרונים כתבו שאין לחוש לחומרא זו ועי' בתשובת ושב הכהן סי' ל"ד

Comment: This is all bedieved. Do those who argue on the bach allow her to delay lechatchila?

Comment: The later poskim use a case of forgetting which is bdieved. However the Shach doesn’t mention that it’s bdieved himself. Having said that, it is a good point, however, in a case with a makka it might also be considered bdieved